# Getting my font to work as a "fall-back" without calling it

Tags: ios, fonts, uifont

I'm working with Chinese characters. Some of my characters do not exist in Unicode. I'm using a PUA .ttf to support my non-universal characters.

When I call

`UIFont fontWithName:@"BabelStoneHanPUA"`

everything is hunky-dory and I get my nice beautiful characters [the second one to be precise].

[image]

When I don't call anything I just get a:

> �

(read: big ugly question mark).

[image]

Although `UIFont fontWithName:@"BabelStoneHanPUA"` doesn't seem to mess anything up, I would really just love my already included, available font to work as a "fall-back" or to work without having to call it.

Is there anyway I can get my PUA font to work without sepecifically setting it as **the** font?

Comment: Does https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIFont's section on font fallback not work?

Answer (score 2):

1. Before using a font, call this method to add a fallback.

   ```
   func addFallbackToFont(font: UIFont, fallbackFontName: String) -> UIFont {
       let originalDescriptor = font.fontDescriptor

       let fallbackDescriptor = originalDescriptor.addingAttributes([.name: fallbackFontName])
       let repairedDescriptor = originalDescriptor.addingAttributes([.cascadeList: [fallbackDescriptor]])

       return UIFont(descriptor: repairedDescriptor, size: 0.0)
   }
   ```
2. If your characters is already exists in the original font, call this method to remove these characters after add fallback.

   ```
   func removeCharacters(characterString: String, font: UIFont) -> UIFont {
       let originalDescriptor = font.fontDescriptor

       var characterSet = (originalDescriptor.object(forKey: .characterSet) as! NSCharacterSet).mutableCopy() as! CharacterSet
       characterSet.remove(charactersIn: characterString)
       let removedDescriptor = originalDescriptor.addingAttributes([.characterSet: characterSet])

       return UIFont(descriptor: removedDescriptor, size: 0.0)
   }
   ```